# jQuery: not(".selected") excluding a class not working as expected! How to fix?

Tags: jquery, css

```
.selected {
    background-color: blue;
}
</style>

<table id="tb">
    <tr class="b"><td>One</td></tr>
    <tr class="b"><td>Two</td></tr>
    <tr class="b"><td>Three</td></tr>
</table>

<script>
        $("#tb tr.b").not(".selected").click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("selected");
        });
</script>
```

The `<tr>` element at first doesn't has the class ".selected" but when clicked it is added to it:

`<tr class="b selected"><td>Two</td></tr>`

Now; the clicked row has the class ".selected"; so it must not be matched with this jQuery selector `$("#tb tr.b").not(".selected")` because it excludes those with the class value ".selected". But the surprising thing is that it still get matched!!.

I need to exclude the row once it has the class ".selected" added, How?

Answer (score 2):

The selector is matched at the time that you execute it. When you bind the event none of the elements has the class, and adding the class to them later doesn't change the binding.

To make the event binding change depending on the class you can use a delegated event, so that the selector is evaluated when the event happens:

```
$("#tb").on("click", "tr.b:not(.selected)", function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you bind a listener with `click`, the set of matched elements `$("#tb tr.b").not(".selected")` isn’t re-checked every time. You bind to elements, not to selector matches.

If you need to make them “selectable” *once*, you could simplify all that to this:

```
$("#tb tr.b").click(function () {
  $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

After all, you need to make elements that aren’t `.selected` yet `.selected`, but not the other way around, right?

Answer (score 0):

When you run `$("#tb tr.b").not(".selected").click...` you bind click callback on tr that doesn't have selected at the moment.

You should check class when you process a click

```
$("#tb tr.b").click(function () {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  }
});
```